# Why can't I clip vectors with 2 different projections?

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS.  I am trying to clip parcel data with a stream buffer.  The two have different projections.  Parcels are NAD83 State plane feet and streams are NAD83 State plane meters.  I keep getting an error that says something like

`detected different projections,  some data may not disply correctly`.

When it runs the clip the output file has no data in it. I have enabled on the fly projection.

Answer (score 4):

For a successful clipping, it is necessary to have the datasets in the **same** projection.

Jut rightclick on one of your layers, `Save As ...` and choose the CRS of the other one.

On-the-fly reprojection is just for visualization of the data, and not helpful for clipping.